# How to ask turtles to place in a desired area, on Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I want to create turtles, which they place in a desired area with random coordinate: [image]

they should place in the white area and in middle of it in a line. in other words, in the top regtangle, their xcor should be random and their ycor is 10. in the right regtangle, their ycor should be random and their xcor is 10 and so on.

Comment: Please edit your picture to not have so much white space around it

Comment: @JenB thank you. edited

Answer (score 1):

When you create turtles, you can give them instructions such as their location. For example:

```
create-turtles 1 [ set ycor 10 ]
```

Alternatively, you can sprout the turtles from the relevant patches and their location will already be set. For example:

```
ask n-of 5 patches with [pcolor > 1] [ sprout 1 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
to place-on-color [#color]
  let _patches (patches with [pcolor = #color])
  ask turtles [
    move-to one-of (_patches with [not any? turtles-here])
  ]
end
```

Add error checking if you may have too many turtles.  (Or remove the unique occupancy constraint if you don't want it.)

Comment: actually I want to for example 30 turtles place randomly in the white space

Comment: @user3397145 Is that all your  turtles, or a subset of them?  If all, the code will do it for you.  If a subset, it is easily modified.  Or if you mean that moving to the center of a random white patch is not "random enough" (you want to use other parts of the patch too), that is slightly more work.